# Zebra QLn320 Link-OS USB communications error

Tags: java, eclipse, usb, zebra-printers

-Hi
I'm using the Zebra Link-OS SDK to play around with a QLn-320 mobile printer. I have not altered any of the code. The printer is able to communicate through a network but not via USB. It is using the ZDesigner QLn320 driver on a USB port. I know the problem isn't the USB because I am able to perform SGD commands via Zebra Toolbox as well as print documents through notepad. The sample code should print out a 60 byte sample logo, instead the application returns "Communications error" in the form of a red label. It doesn't even seem to read anything from the printer as I don't get anything returned by doing a SGD command. It seems to work about 1% of the time and other times it shows the blinking folder icon but nothing happens. I've tried all the firmwares for the printer listed on Zebra's website including the latest one. I've tried deleting the project, re-importing it, cleaning it, and even using NetBeans, but nothing seems to work. The bug seems to be in the SDK.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are running JRE v1.6 or above.

Comment: The sample SDK code is running JRE v1.7 and an application I've made is using 1.6. Both applications are working with a network configuration but still not USB.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a factory default on the printer.

You can do this by sending to the printer the following SGD command:

! U1 do "device.restore_defaults" "all"

Then try printing from the app via USB.

Comment: The SGD didn't work. The app briefly connects only to disconnect before it can send a test label. I've found a similar connection issue with WLAN in the official iOS Link-OS SDK, perhaps there is a similar issue.

Comment: What platform are running on?  Windows XP, 7, Linux?